# java.net.SocketException in a rest client

Tags: java, rest, grails

I have a rest client that reads and saves user's data into a database. The rest client works fine. But unfortunately the server starts giving exception after a day or so, and things start working as soon as I restart the app.

stacktrace:

```
Line | Method
->>  113 | socketWrite            in java.net.SocketOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    159 | write                  in     ''
|     82 | flushBuffer . . . . .  in java.io.BufferedOutputStream
|    140 | flush                  in     ''
|   3969 | send . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2598 | sendCommand            in     ''
|   2778 | sqlQueryDirect . . . . in     ''
|   2828 | execSQL                in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   5372 | setAutoCommit . . . .  in     ''
|    101 | doCall                 in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
|     16 | $tt__getUserDTOByEmail in com.fame.ums.UserService
|     45 | get                    in com.fame.ums.UserController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter               in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

After I searched for the cause on internet I got to a few things

1. There might be a memory leak
2. The rest client socket gets closed and the code has not yet been notified.

Can you please guide me on how can I check this and what should I start looking for?

Comment: I also face this problem , I have to restart the app to get it working. Good question

Comment: obviously you have a problem with your DB connection pool. Try to tune the `DataSource` configuration, with smth. like `autoReconnect=true`